# Add partial view to view on a schedule

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

My goal is to add data to the table from the controller every 10 minutes. I tried using Quartz, Coravel, Sheduler different, but nothing works because they only allow background tasks that do not return anything.

Comment: have you tried Timer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @JobesK, Of course I tried it, it can only perform background tasks, that is, through delegates that cannot return anything

Comment: well you didn't list it but "of course" you tried it,, post your code show results